# Control table names Entity Framework Generate Database from Model

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

I was working with entity framework in a database first style. Each time I wanted to update my edmx file I did just that, ran update model.

The problem I now have is that I've lost my database (long boring story, it was on a disk that's been formatted and I don't have a backup). I thought I would be able to use the 'Generate Database from Model' option to at the least get the structure of my database back. The problem I have is that the tool automatically pluralises all the table names, so `Cost` becomes `Costs` and so on. This breaks the EF model as it is expecting the table `Cost` so I can no longer run an 'Update Model from Database' as the table `Cost` does not exist. How can I control the table tables that are used when generating a database from a model?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the `Entity Set Name` property was wrong for all of my entities, changing that to a non pluralised version gave me a sql script that created the tables in a form that could then be synchronised with the EF model.

Comment: I want my `Entity Set Names` to be pluralised, just not my freaking table names. Having a pluralised entity set name is not wrong; the behaviour of the DB generator is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop EF from generating pluralized names, you can disable that by clicking on the empty space on your *.edmx file, and in Properties there is a field called "Pluralize New Objects" and change it from True to False.

Comment: This seems to have to effect for me.